# Custom scope in Windsor for shared REST resource in MVC3 framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Right now my ThingController's methods all take an id parameter that identifies the resource, i.e. the URLs are /{controller}/{action}/{id}. So of course the first thing that *every* method does is var thing = thingFactory.Get(id). Now, a Thing is a live, thread-safe, runtime object that is shared across multiple users and sessions.

So what I want to be able to do is have the DI framework use the id to fetch the Thing from a custom scope ("lifestyle?") and inject it into the per-request controller. It should also create a new Thing if no thing exists for that id yet.

Comment: Question: are you trying inject the Thing to the Controller in order to remove the "var thing = thingFactory.Get(id)" lines in all methods? If so, i think it would be better to configure at the MVC level rather than the IoC Container level.

Comment: @raulg That is what I'm trying to do, yes. How do I do that "at the MVC level"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying inject the Thing to the Controller in order to remove the "var thing = thingFactory.Get(id)" lines in all methods, you could use an ASP.NET MVC custom Model Binder to execute the retrieval before the start of your method code.

If your route looks like: /{controller}/{action}/{id} , then you will have the id look up your value.

Model binding will allow your method signature to look like:

```
public ActionResult SomeDetails(int id, Thing thing)
{
```

Model Binding and validation fires *before* the method code executes. The DefaultModelBinder will only populate your class from the FormCollection, or other non-persistent sources.

The trick i'm recommending is to provide a custom model binder (IModelBinder) for the Thing class, which executes your lookup. Derive from DefaultModelBinder, inject your IThingFactory, and override the BindModel() to do the lookup your way.

```
public class ThingModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    IThingFactory ThingFactory;

    public ThingModelBinder(IThingFactory thingFactory)
    {
        this.IThingFactory = thingFactory;
    }

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        Thing thing = new Thing();

        string id_string = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
        int id = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(id_string, out id);
        var thing = thingFactory.Get(id);

        return thing;
    }

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }

        // custom section
        object model = this.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, typeof(Thing));

        // set back to ModelBindingContext
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = model;

        // call base class version
        // this will use the overridden version of CreateModel() which calls the Repository
        // object model = BindComplexModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

    }
```

Then you would configure the model binder in global.asax Application_Start(), where you would already be creating the container:

```
    // Custom Model Binders
    System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(
        typeof(MyCompany.Thing)
        , new MyMvcApplication.ModelBinders.ThingModelBinder(
            WindsorContainer.Resolve<IThingFactory>()
            )
        );
```

That will cause your custom model binder to be called.

You resolve the Windsor dependencies the normal way.

This is based on [a post i did](http://enehana.nohea.com/general/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binder-safe-updates-for-unspecified-fields/).

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, you have some fixed number of `Things` that are registered with the container and you want a factory that returns the thing with a given ID such that if you say `Get(1)` twice you will get the same `Thing` each time and if you say `Get(2)` you will get a different thing.

One way you can acheieve this is with the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) like so:

```
// This is the thing factory - it will create the thing if it has not already 
// been created with the given ID - if it is already created it will return 
// that instance
public interface IThingFactory
{
    Thing Get(int id);
}

// This is the thing - it has an ID and a method that you
// can call that keeps track of how many times it has been
// called (so you can be sure it is the same instance)
public class Thing
{
    private int _count;

    public Thing(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public int HowManyCalls()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
    }
}

// This is a typed factory selector to manage selecting the component from
// the container by using the name ("Thing" followed by the ID)
public class GetThingComponentSelector : ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    public TypedFactoryComponent SelectComponent(MethodInfo method, 
                                                 Type type, 
                                                 object[] arguments)
    {
        return new TypedFactoryComponent("Thing" + arguments[0],
                                         typeof(Thing),
                                         new Arguments(arguments));
    }
}

// .... In the installer ....

// Register each thing with a different name that matches the ID
// and register a custom component selector and the thing factory
container
    .AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()
    .Register(
        Component
            .For<Thing>()
            .Named("Thing1"),
        Component
            .For<Thing>()
            .Named("Thing2"),
        Component
            .For<GetThingComponentSelector>(),
        Component
            .For<IThingFactory>()
            .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith<GetThingComponentSelector>()));

// ... Some demo code (you do not need to resolve the factory directly)

// Now resolve the same thing twice and then a different thing and make sure
// Windsor has handled the lifestyle
var thing = container.Resolve<IThingFactory>().Get(1);
Console.WriteLine("ID should be 1 and is " + thing.Id 
    + ". Calls should be 1 and is " + thing.HowManyCalls());

thing = container.Resolve<IThingFactory>().Get(1);
Console.WriteLine("ID should be 1 and is " + thing.Id 
    + ". Calls should be 2 and is " + thing.HowManyCalls());

thing = container.Resolve<IThingFactory>().Get(2);
Console.WriteLine("ID should be 2 and is " + thing.Id 
    + ". Calls should be 1 and is " + thing.HowManyCalls());
```

There, you see I use the ID as the "name" in the container and then look up the name using the custom selector.  There are probably other ways to do it, but I think, based on your question, that should hopefully at least get you started.